# Ubuntu 12.10 Low Graphics Mode

Tags: graphics, login, 12.10

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 in my HP Pavilion d6 having Nvidia GeForce GT 630M. Now I'm not able to boot into Ubuntu. I get a error saying that the system is running in low-graphics mode. In the next step when it asks me chose what to do i chose "Run in low-graphics mode for just one session and the screen goes blank. This is happening in Ubuntu 12.10 not 12.04.