# How to install NVIDIA driver in ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: nvidia, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop does not show when I installed nvidia drivers!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202574/desktop-does-not-show-when-i-installed-nvidia-drivers)

I've downloaded "NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.60.run" from NVDIA website...

Tried to execute it in command promptmode (Grub boot menu--> ubuntu Advanced options) 
But the filesystem is Read only so the installer failed.

HOW TO MAKE THE FILESYSTEM R/W???

Comment: Take a look at this answer : [Ubuntu 12.10 Low Graphics Mode](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203374/ubuntu-12-10-low-graphics-mode/203380#203380)

Comment: @JorgeCastro This question is about how to install the NVidia drivers in the first place, and not about any problem with the drivers themselves, so this is almost certainly not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @JorgeCastro That doesn't seem to be related to `/` being mounted as ro instead of rw.

Comment: @vyshakh99 what makes you say the file system is read only? Did you receive an error that told you this? Where is the file located? Is it in /home/yourusername/Downloads or in another location your user doesn't own? Also, look at the link in Jorge's comment. Did you use sudo? and is the file executable?