# 12.10 64-bit does not want to work with the GTX 670

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 64-bit, 12.10

I have been trying to install Quantal AMD64 on the following PC:

- *ASUS P8Z77-I Deluxe LGA (Z77-based)*
- *Ivy Bridge i5-3570K (overclocked but why would that matter?)*
- *EVGA GTX 670*
- *Dual Samsung 830 Series SSDs*

Unfortunately, the quetzal seems hellbent on disappointing me. Here's how:

1. Live CD doesn't even start properly. Display is filled with colorful noise, though I can see the mouse moving.
2. Installation, however, works just fine. No display issues and no errors during installation.
3. When booted, sometimes I get colorful noise on screen and a hang and sometimes I get the "Running in low graphics mode error" with my mouse and keyboard maybe working and maybe not. When I click *OK*, the system hangs in the next dialog screen -- the one that offers the various options to deal with the issue.
4. I tried getting into recovery and using the console to install the latest nVidia drivers as per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203374/ubuntu-12-10-low-graphics-mode). That didn't work: the system would hang randomly while I was in the middle of running the commands.
5. Switched to the integrated GPU and that actually worked. I got desktop, opened the terminal, and installed the driver.
6. Switched back to the discrete GPU and it still didn't work. The system would hang midway and *at random points* during the initialization process -- usually in the first 1-2 seconds. I can't boot into recovery (hangs before it). Can't even boot when I switched back to the iGPU.
7. Somehow, the OS managed to roll my MB's clock by 7 hrs. Insult to injury.

Now, I'm stuck. I am 99% sure it's the bleepin' graphics driver but sometimes with Linux you never know for sure. People have obviously gotten their Kepler-based GPUs to run fine under Ubuntu so what gives?!

Please let me know if you have managed to pull the above feat of strength. I have to know what incantations you used and what animal you sacrificed.